# How do you programmatically get the size/weight (MB) of a dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

I could navigate to the library path in the file explorer and search for my dataset.sas7bdat file and look at it's size.
But that's not practical. I'm not even sure where the WORK library is located and even if I did it's on a remote server making it complicated to access.

Is it possible to print the size/weight of a dataset in the log or a report?

> using SAS EG 7.1 and SAS 9.3

Motive : I want to do that because I will try to reduce a dataset size and I would like to know how much I gained.

Comment: Did you run PROC CONTENTS on the dataset in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL dictionary view `dictionary.tables` :

```
/* Return libref, dataset name, # records, filesize & % compression */
proc sql ;
  create table size1 as
  select libname, memname, nlobs, filesize, pcompress
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname = 'MYDATA' 
  ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your library uses the BASE engine, you can use the `pathname()` function to find it.  After that you can use the sashelp views to get the filesize.  You could also use os commands, but for that you need x command enabled.

The following demonstrates:

```
%let libds=WORK.SAMPLE;
/* create demo data */
data &libds;
  retain string 'blaaaaaaaah';
  do x=1 to 10000;
    output;
  end;
run;
/* extract library and datasaet from libds variable */
%let lib=%scan(&libds,1,.);
%let ds =%scan(&libds,2,.);
/* set up filename to point directly at the dataset */
/* note - if you have indexes you also need to do   */
/* this for the .sas7bndx extension                 */
filename fref "%sysfunc(pathname(&lib))/&ds..sas7bdat";
/* query dictionary view for file attributes        */
data _null_;
  set sashelp.vextfl(where=(fileref='FREF'));
  filesize=filesize/(1024**2); /* size in MB */
  putlog filesize= 'MB';
run;
/* clear libref */
filename fref clear;
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I got 50% reduction (from 567 to 284 MB) from proper variable lengths.

Comment: Good stufff! You can also look at dataset compression to reduce size, if this is an issue ( `options compress=yes`)